# Alamofire: NSLocalizedFailure error (status code 403)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift2, alamofire

I am trying to retrieve the various user ids from `task api`, perform a loop on them and POST the array of values to `submitScore api`.

Desired workflow:

> User taps on table cell -> app *gets* the cell id and display items related to that cell -> user presses a button -> app gets stores data in the form of an array and POSTS to an submitScore api

I can retrieve the various user data with a `GET` request from `task api` but I don't know how to:

- associate my retrieved ids with the cell id
- store the retrieved data (user ids and score) in an array and POST it to my `submitScore api` in the form below

Array form for POST body:

```
{  "ratings": [{
   "safety_rating_id": 105,
   "schedule_job_id": 18,
   "score": 9,
   "submission_id": 27
   }, 
   {
   "safety_rating_id": 105,
   "schedule_job_id": 18,
   "score": 9,
   "submission_id": 27
   }]
}
```

Which is why I get thrown this error:

> Request failed with error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error Code=-6003 "Response status code was unacceptable: 403" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Response status code was unacceptable: 403}

Code for POST:

```
 func getTaskDetails(onCompletion: () -> (), onError: ((NSError) -> ())? = nil) {

 guard let endPoint = Data.sharedInstance.submitScoreEndpoint  
 else { print("Empty endpoint"); return }

 let user = Users()

 let Auth_header = [
        "Authorization" : user.token,
        ]

 let parameters = [
        "ratings" : [
            [
                "safety_rating_id" : 106,
                "schedule_job_id" : 18,
                "score" : 10,
                "submission_id" : 27
            ],
            [
                "safety_rating_id" : 105,
                "schedule_job_id" : 18,
                "score" : 9,
                "submission_id" : 27
            ]
        ]
    ]

  Alamofire.request(.POST, endPoint, headers: Auth_header, parameters: parameters)
        .validate()
        .responseData {
        response in

        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let data):
            let json = JSON(data)
            print(json)
            onCompletion()
        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            onError?(error)
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The API you are posting to is giving a 403 http error, telling you that something in you post is not allowed. With the documentation of your API we can't tel what is wrong. It could also mean that your post does not include authentication.

Comment: @rckoenes I understand, I also have issues sending a POST request with an array in the parameter using alamofire. Could you help me with that?